# Select subset of data.table columns based on observations in a given row

Tags: r, data.table

I have data similar to this:

```
DT <- data.table(name=c("a","b","c","total"),measure1=c(1,1,1,3),
                 measure2=c(1,1,2,4),measure3=c(2,2,2,6),measure4=c(3,3,3,9))

    name measure1 measure2 measure3 measure4
1:     a        1        1        2        3
2:     b        1        1        2        3
3:     c        1        2        2        3
4: total        3        4        6        9
```

I would like to select the `name` column and all columns where the last row (with "total" in the `name` column) is greater than 5.  The desired output is this:

```
    name measure3 measure4
1:     a        2        3
2:     b        2        3
3:     c        2        3
4: total        6        9
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `DT[, DT[.N][, c(TRUE,.SD > 5), .SDcols = -1], with = FALSE]`

Comment: An alternative to @akrun's solution: `DT[, .SD, .SDcols = DT[name == "total", c(TRUE, .SD > 5), .SDcols = -1]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both @akrun and @Jaap for posting their answers using data.table in the comments above.  Both work perfectly and are great solutions with some stylistic differences between the two.  For completeness, here are the two answers:

`DT[, DT[.N][, c(TRUE,.SD > 5), .SDcols = -1], with = FALSE]`

and

`DT[, .SD, .SDcols = DT[name == "total", c(TRUE, .SD > 5), .SDcols = -1]]`

Answer (score 1):

A gather-spread-gather `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DT %>% 
  gather(key,val,-name) %>% 
   spread(name,val) %>% 
   filter(total>5) %>% 
   gather(name,val,-key) %>% 
   spread(key,val)
   name measure3 measure4
1     a        2        3
2     b        2        3
3     c        2        3
4 total        6        9
```

Comment: thanks for this.  This works perfectly for a dplyr/tidyr solution.